# Project fails to build because KIF classes are missing

Tags: objective-c, ios, kif-framework

Project fails to build because KIF classes are missing.

I am trying with a simple app and have strictly followed the github [readme](https://github.com/square/KIF). Also, I have double checked whatever is mentioned in the read me for this issue. I still cant make my app build/ run the tests.

Can anyone kindly help me with this issue ?

Thanks.
Ahsan

Error :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/ahsan/Desktop/Others/LoginExampleKIF/libKIF.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/ahsan/Desktop/Others/LoginExampleKIF/libKIF.a (2 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KIFTestController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_EXTestController in EXTestController.o

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KIFTestScenario", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EXTestController.o
      objc-class-ref in KIFTestScenario+EXAdditions.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_KIFTestScenario_$_EXAdditions in KIFTestScenario+EXAdditions.o

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KIFTestStep", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in KIFTestScenario+EXAdditions.o
      objc-class-ref in KIFTestStep+EXAdditions.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_KIFTestStep_$_EXAdditions in KIFTestStep+EXAdditions.o

  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_KIFTestController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_EXTestController in EXTestController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I also had trouble with KIF and double checked the readme.  I ended up removing the KIF project from my workspace and adding it again and it started working.  Also, what errors are you getting?

Comment: @JamesZaghini : added the output. :-s (lil messed up with the formatting, though !). Ok, let me remove KIF and try again. Thanks for the suggestion. But, nope. No luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message, it seems like you are trying to run your app on the simulator, but aren't building for the i386 architecture.

I just checked KIF out from github, and at this time it's not set up to build for i386

Set your "Architectures" & "Valid Architectures" to i386, armv7 & armv7s.  Then clean and build again.  You may need to do this for your own app's target too, but I assume your app would be set to build for i386 also, unless you removed it.

[image: After]

Let me know how you go :D

Comment: Oddly it is working for me, even that the only valid architectures are armv7 and armv7s in project configuration.